# Excel Tooltips is not display in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development

I am setting up the SharePoint 2010 BI environment.

- When I upload "PowerPivot Excel" document into SharePoint under document library, the Tooltips on chart is displayed as "Excel Chart or image".
- I can see "Value, Category and Series" tooltips when I open with Excel and hover on the chart.
- Using "Excel Web Access" also could not configure the tooltips that I want.

Please kindly guide me, if somebody know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Excel Services provides a subset of the features of Excel. Detailed ToolTips are not shown when viewing in the browser.

You can find a list of supported and unsupported features here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595319%28v=office.14%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your information, Steven. Do you think it is an unsupported feature?

Comment: I think it is just ignored by the web rendering, not so much unsupported. The tips will still be there, but only when opening the workbook in Excel.